# Apache solr : Search across multivalued fields

Tags: php, apache, solr, lucene

I have a multivalued field "Name" and need perform search across that field

I need to get results like Name =  'john doe' OR name='peter joe'.

How should i write filter query to get above result.

I used filter query like

```
fq=name:(john doe OR peter joe)
```

but somehow its not working.

Comment: You have to enclose or escape the strings properly, as you're now probably searching for john, doe OR peter, joe. Try name:("john doe" OR "peter joe"). Your field type will also affect this.

Comment: field type is strings, I tried to quote names as well , but it did not return any results

Comment: Remember that a StrField will require the same case as well.

Comment: ok , need to check this